# How I can Retry a curl in php

Tags: php

if i made a request to check proxy Status, but the proxy is dead, how I can retry the request with another proxy

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://p.webshare.io:80');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'vxoydhen-rotate:hrpofeus0rx0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-api.com/json/');
```

Comment: Why not set the other proxy afterwards, and rerun the request? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to make

Answer (score 1):

The request will be initiated when you call `curl_exec()` ([documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)). That command will return false on failure. So, you can try the request again, if it returns false.

Also, you can use `curl_errno` to check for errors in the request and then check the http_code of the `curl_getinfo()` function.

```
$ch = curl_init();

// the setopt function just sets up parameters for the upcoming curl_exec call
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://p.webshare.io:80');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'vxoydhen-rotate:hrpofeus0rx0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-api.com/json/');

// start the request
$result = curl_exec();

// you can also check if an error was triggered
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  // see the raw request info (maybe check the http_code property)
  var_dump($info);
  $result = false;
}

curl_close($ch);

if ($result === false) {
  // the request failed, so you can try a new one
}
```

NOTE: `php_curl` extension can not retry an already executed session. You can only start a new one.